# C - end program without terminating created threads

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety

Is it wrong for a C program to create a few threads, and after receiving some signal to exit without cleanly terminating all the threads and waiting for the main thread to join them?

Comment: It is not good practice. Ending the program will of course abort all threads but you don't know what state each thread is in at the time it gets aborted - perhaps it needs to clean up or release resources that are not normally released by simply ending the process.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to do it another way